# Break out of proprietary toolbox after a given time

Tags: matlab, timeout, break

I am iterating through a large test matrix in MATLAB and calling second-party proprietary software (running in MATLAB) each time. I cannot edit the software source code. Sometimes, the software hangs, so I want to exit it after a certain amount of time and move on to the next iteration.

In pseudocode, I'm doing this:

```
for i = 1:n
    output(i) = proprietary_software(input(i));
end
```

How can I skip to the next iteration (and possibly save `output(i)='too_long'`) if the proprietary software is taking too long?

Comment: I think you can do it using [Timer Callback Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html). I am going to try see if I can get some code working...

Comment: Hmmm... I was hoping you could just put this in a `try`-`catch` block and have a timer object throw an error. But it seems that the timer objects call back function happens in a way (probably a different thread) that the error it throws is not recognized by the `try`-`catch` :/

Comment: This does not look promising: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/335089.  Maybe you could attempt some sort of threading but I think this will be very messy: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1

Comment: How are you calling the outside software? Are you using `system` or equivalent or is it through a dll or jar file?

Comment: @TimAdams It's proprietary software that runs directly in the matlab environment. Specifically, it's [GPOPS-II](http://www.gpops2.com/). So, after defining `setup` and a coupe other functions using the GPOPS syntax, I call it using a function: `output = gpops2(setup);`

Comment: @Delyle that makes things easier. Try setting a `tic/toc` around it and if the `toc` has not triggered within a set amount of time, move to the next iterations

Comment: You may be able to use dbstop, etc. to step through the GPOPS line by line and decide if a time limit has been exceeded then exit if need be. Not sure if they will have blocked this by overloading the debug functions, or putting checks for debugging in the code though.

Comment: @Adriaan I've tried the `tic/toc` solution but it doesn't work. There is a way using the GPOPS-II syntax to check if too much time has attached by calling toc, but all I can do is break out with an error, which halts the loop completely.

Comment: @TDevlin I can indeed enter debug mode and exit if I want to, but it doesn't help me in my current case. First, it involves being ever present when my loop is running, which is not optimal. Second, if too much time has elapsed, all I can do is halt the operation and restart the for loop where I left off manually- however, I would like to do this automatically.

Comment: Can you use the    tic/toc solution in conjunction with try catch blocks? you could throw an error, and let the catch block handle it, possibly wrap it all in a while true  style loop to keep things moving ?

Comment: How *exactly* is the code hanging? E.g. is it an infinite loop of MATLAB code, or  is it running a builtin function indefinitely, or running a mex file indefinitely? Can you exit the hanging program using ctrl+c?

Comment: @TDevlin @user664303 the `try/catch` block with `tic/toc` sort of works, because the proprietary software has to repeatedly call a function that I define. However, it occasionally hangs in a MEX file (specifically [SNOPT 7](http://ampl.com/products/solvers/solvers-we-sell/snopt/?gclid=Cj0KEQiAqemzBRDh2vGKmMnqoegBEiQAqJPuyGLBDwAeZWYtAqu-A4-eYmE3TZi8udPvveFrQzZWQSQaAgx18P8HAQ)); most recently this took over an hour despite the `try/catch` block, and eventually caused a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call Matlab from another instance of Matlab. The other instance of Matlab will run the command and release control to the first instance of Matlab to wait while it either saves the results or reaches a certain time. In this case, it will wait 30 seconds.

You will need 1 additional function. Make sure this function is on the Matlab path.

```
function proprietary_software_caller(input)
    hTic=tic;
    output=proprietary_software(input);
    hToc=toc(hTic);
    if hToc<30
       save('outfile.mat','output');
    end
    exit;
end
```

You will need to modify your original script this way

```
[status,firstPID] = str2double(system('for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in (''tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Matlab.exe" /fo csv) do @echo %~F'')'));

for i = 1:n
    inputStr=num2str(input(i));
    system(['matlab.exe -nodesktop -r proprietary_software_caller\(',inputStr,'\)&']);
    hTic=tic;
    hToc=toc(hTic);
    while hToc<30 || ~(exist('outfile.mat','file')==2)
       hToc=toc(hTic);
    end
    if hToc>=30
        output(i)= 'too_long';
        [status,allPIDs]=str2double(system('for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %F in (''tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Matlab.exe" /fo csv) do @echo %~F'')'));
        allPIDs(allPIDs==firstPID)=[];
        for a=1:numel(allPIDs)
           [status,cmdout]=system(['taskkill /F /pid ' sprintf('%i',allPIDs(a))]);
        end
    elseif exist('outfile.mat','file')==2
        loadedData=load('outfile.mat');
        output(i)=loadedData.output;
        delete('outfile.mat');
    end
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why can't you set the `tic/toc` in one instance of MATLAB, or, in other words, why do you need the `system` call?

Comment: After debugging your code above, I mostly got it to work with a minimal working example. However, there's a problem; even though the main script will have moved on if one instance of MATLAB takes too long, that same instance will keep running. So, eventually it might spit out an `outfile.mat` that _doesn't_ correspond to the current iteration.

Comment: Delyle, you could always add a tic/toc in the first function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Adriaan the `system` call is used to launch the other instance of Matlab to automate the loop. This will allow the script to call the function in the background.

Comment: I know that is what `system` does, but why can't you do the `tic/toc` with breakout `while` in a single MATLAB instance, so without the necessity of `system`

Comment: @Adriaan, the reason is that Matlab will get stuck in the proprietary software that Delyle is using. You could ctrl-C and break out of it, then continue the loop, but that wouldn't be effective. You cannot break out of a function in Matlab until it is finished. The only other options would involve the Parallel Computing toolbox or using a parallelization trick from [UndocumentedMatlab](http://www.undocumentedmatlab.com)

Comment: Your updated solution is nice, now bad outputs won't be saved, but the hanging calls to the proprietary software will still eat up the processor. Is there a way to kill a particular instance of matlab after a certain amount of time?

**PS** You need to take the second boolean condition of the while loop and put it in an if/then statement in the body of the loop, i.e. `while  hToc<30;if exist('outfile.mat','file')==2; break;end;end`. Otherwise the loop won't break until `hToc>=30`.

Comment: @Delyle, can you edit the answer with that change? I also added some code that will get the current Matlab process and then kill the additional Matlab processes if they are taking too long.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the change in the while loop, just waiting for peer review. In the meantime, I tried your updated implementation, but get the error `Error using str2double. Too many output arguments.`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of Matlab that I can use, but could you post the output of the system command? We can work on the string from there.

Comment: The issue comes about with the call `[status,firstPID]  = str2double(system(...))`. You should write this as `[status,firstPID]  = system(...)`.

Comment: With some modification, I got this script to work for my problem. I am working on a mac so I had to translate the system commands to unix... so I can't comment on how well they work on windows. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking for a way to implement a timeout on MATLAB code. This can be surprisingly tricky to implement. The first thing to state is that if the MATLAB code in question cannot terminate itself, either by exiting cleanly or throwing an error, then it is **not** possible to terminate the code without quitting or killing the MATLAB process in question. For example, throwing an error in an externally created timer does not work; the error is caught.

The first question to ask is therefore:

> Can the over-running code be made to terminate itself?

This depends on the cause to the over-run, and also your access to the source code:

- If the program gets stuck in an infinite (or very long-running) loop, either in MATLAB code or a mex file for which you have source code, or which calls a user-defined callback each iteration, then you can get this code to terminate itself.
- If the program gets stuck inside a MATLAB builtin, or a p-code file or mex file for which you don't have the source code, and doesn't have support for calling a callback regularly, then it won't be possible for you to get the code to terminate itself.

Let's address the first case. The easiest way to get the code to terminate itself is to get it to throw an error, which is caught by the caller, if it exceeds the timeout time. E.g. in the OP's case:

```
for i = 1:n
    tic();
    try
        output(i) = proprietary_software(input(i));
    catch
    end
end
```

with the following code somewhere in the over-running loop, or called in a loop callback or mex file:

```
assert(toc() < 10, 'Timed out');
```

Now for the second case. You need to kill this MATLAB process, so it makes sense for this to be a MATLAB process you have spawned from your current MATLAB session. You can do this using a system call similar to this:

```
system('matlab -nodisplay -r code_to_run()')
```

While it is possible for a MATLAB process to quit itself in some situations which could be of use here (e.g. a timer function calling `quit('force')`), the most reliable way of killing a MATLAB process is to do it with a system call, using `taskkill` (Windows) or `kill` (Linux/Mac).

A framework using the approach of spawning and killing timed-out MATLAB processes might work like this:

1. Using system calls, launch one or more new MATLAB processes from your MATLAB session, running the code you want.
2. Use the file system or a memory mapped file to communicate between the MATLAB processes the function inputs, loop progress, outputs, process ids and timeout times.
3. Use the original MATLAB process to check the timeout times haven't been reached, or if so to terminate the process in question and instantiate a new one.
4. Use the original MATLAB process to collect up the function outputs (either from the filesystem or memory mapped file) and exit. Workers should terminate when there is no more work left

I provide a sketch only because a full working implementation of this approach is fairly involved, and in fact it has already been implemented and is publicly available in the [batch_job toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44077-batch-job). In the OP's case, using this toolbox (with a 10 second timeout) you'd call:

```
output = batch_job(@proprietary_software, input(:)', '-timeout', 10);
```

Note that for the toolbox to work, its root directory needs to be on your MATLAB path at startup.

Comment: This solution actually worked for me. It's lucky that the software I'm using (GPOPS-II) cycles through a function that I myself have to define. So, I can place the `assert` call in that function, even though I can't access any of the functions that come bundled with GPOPS-II. I'm going to hold off accepting the answer for the moment, and try the other solutions as well.

Comment: **Update to my last comment**: While the try/catch idea worked most of the time, the program occasionally hangs in a MEX file; most recently this took over an hour despite the try/catch block, and eventually caused a segmentation fault. So this solution is better than nothing, but I'll be trying something else for the long term.

Comment: If a mex file hangs you have no other choice but to kill the MATLAB process  externally. Same if a MATLAB builtin hangs.

Comment: The batch_job toolbox now supports killing MATLAB processes externally. I've updated the answer to reflect this approach, which should work with R2015a.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't work for me, as my function outputs are structures, which `batch_job` can't handle. However, I still have issues running this on R2015a for Mac. A simple test case hangs. The MWE is `input = [1e4,1e5,1e6,1e7]`, `function output = long_ode(endpoint);
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-4 1e-4 1e-5]);
[T,Y] = ode45(@rigid,[0 endpoint],[0 1 1],options);
output  = Y(1);
function dy = rigid(t,y)
dy = zeros(3,1);
dy(1) = y(2) * y(3);
dy(2) = -y(1) * y(3);
dy(3) = -0.51 * y(1) * y(2);`
With call `output = batch_job(@long_ode,input(:)','-timeout', 10)`.

Comment: @Delyle: For outputs that don't fit the requirements, you can just write a wrapper function which saves them to a mat file. The latest version of the toolbox fixes some issues. I suggest if you have any more issues you raise them on github.