# Timer function queueing in Matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, timer

I have an issue with a timer function not always running as desired in Matlab.

I am trying to run an external simulation then fire a watcher function which checks the sim has exited correctly after a set time, if not it will force kill the task so it can be started again.

However the function works correctly for the first 2 batches of simulations then ceases to run. I am restarting the timer and using single shot. So each time the sim exits the timer is restarted. The timer callback is the function to kill the sim and the docs say 'Callback functions execute code during some event' which suggests the function should run regardless of any other matlab code. Is this correct or do callbacks work in some other way?

I initially thought this to be an issue with the execution queue holding the matlab worker for the sim, however it doesn't explain why it works for the first 100 or so times.

To be able to solve my issue I need more information on how the matlab workers work with regards to timer call backs. I am aware that unless specified matlab works on a single execution queue but I do not understand how callbacks function in this environment.

Any information regarding when and how timer call backs execute (ie do they fire exactly when timed to do so or do they simply get added to the queue at that time?) and any way of forcing a function to run regardless of the current worker would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using batch() instead of a timer call back but the shell commands do not seem to work in a batch function (I have no idea why).

Many thanks

Comment: I suggest you add the code of your timer to this question... Also this question might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326371/break-out-of-proprietary-toolbox-after-a-given-time

Comment: @Dan thank you for your link it was similar to what I was trying to achieve and helped me greatly. For those looking at this in the future my research suggests the timer callbacks exist on the same MT and so may be paused or halted due to other executions. Creating an external process with java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime(); solved my issue.

Comment: I suggest that you should maybe write your own answer with code snippets.