# Dealing with infinite loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

Is it possible to “catch” infinite loops?
Like catching errors.

So something like:

```
try for 30 seconds
    some_function
catch 
    disp('Took too long!')
end
```

The reason is I don'd want or can't change anything in “some_function”.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326371/break-out-of-proprietary-toolbox-after-a-given-time the short answer is you *do* want to change the function if you can

Comment: Well there are hundreds of this functions and some of them may result in an infinite loop. I have to test how they perform. I'm not supposed to change them.

Comment: Then your only choice is to try one of the answers from the question I linked to.